how to bind slot variable to scoped slots
I am new to vue 3 component and renderer function, just want to use a simple table component with column meta data with slot supports, like below-attached code snippets, I I don't know how to implement the TheColumn part, the slot #header & #cell cannot work in this version. in method 'columns()', the column item doesn't keep header() & cell() objects too.
I googled but didn't find answer yet.
anybody help explain in more details?
thanks.

App.Vue:
 <template>
   <TheTable :data="data">
     <Column label="Name" prop="name" />
     <Column label="City">
       <template #header> {{ translate ? '城市' : 'City' }} </template>
       <template #cell="{item}"> 
          {{ translate ? cities[item.city] || item.city: item.city}}
       </template>
     </Column>
     <Column label="Email">
       <template #cell="{ item }"> {{ item.email }} </template>
     </Column>
   </TheTable>
  </template>

 <script>

   import TheTable from './TheTable.vue';
   import TheColumn from './TheColumn.vue';

   export default {
     name: 'App',
     components: {
       TheTable,
       Column: TheColumn,
    },
    data() {
      return {
       translate: true,
       cities: {
         NY: '纽约',
         LA: '洛杉基',
       },
       data: [
        {
          city: 'NY',
          name: 'Jacky',
          email: 'jacky@google.com'
        },
        {
           city: 'LA',
           name: 'Tom',
           email: 'tom@ibm.com'
        }
      ],
      }
    }
  }
  </script>


TheTable.vue:
 <template>
 <div>
     <table>
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th v-for="(header, column) in columns" :key="column">
                     <slot name="header">{{ header.label }}</slot>
                 </th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr v-for="(row, index) in data" :key="index">
                 <td v-for="(header, column) in columns" :key="column"> 
                     <slot name="cell" :item="row"> {{ row[header.prop] }}  </slot>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
 </template>

 <script>
   export default {
     name: 'TheTable',
     props: {
       data: {
         type: Array,
         required: true
      },
    },
    computed: {
       columns() {
         let list = this.$slots && this.$slots.default && this.$slots.default()
             .filter(e => e.type.name === 'TheColumn')
             .map(slot => {
                 let a = {
                     label: slot.props.label,
                     prop: slot.props.prop,
                     slotHeader: slot.props.header,
                     slotCell: slot.props.cell
                 };
                 return a;
             }) || [];
         console.log('list ' + list);
         return list;
       },
    },
  }
 </script>


TheColumn.vue:
<script>
 const TheColumn = (props, context) => {
 return [];
}

export default TheColumn;
</script>




Playground
Basically you should create an array of header and cell components from the default slot filled with TheColumn to render in TheTable. The only problem is to detect TheColumn in production, I used an isColumn property. Also I

Changed the cell to default slot for more compact column definitions
Used Composition API to make the snippet coding faster, you can refactor it to the Options API

App.vue (the template changed):
<template>
   <TheTable :data="data">
     <Column :label prop="name" />
     <Column>
       <template #header> {{ translate ? '城市' : 'City' }} </template>
       <template  #="{ item }"> {{ translate ? cities[item.city] || item.city: item.city}}</template>
     </Column>
     <Column v-if="showEmail" label="Email" #="{ item }">
       {{ item.email }}
     </Column>
   </TheTable>
   <div style="display:flex; gap: 8px; margin-top:16px">
    <button @click="label = label === 'Name' ? 'Name changed' : 'Name'">Toggle name label</button>
    <button @click="showEmail = !showEmail">Toggle email column</button>
    <button @click="translate = !translate">Toggle translate</button>
   </div>
</template>


TheTable.vue
<script setup>

import {h, useSlots, createTextVNode, computed} from 'vue';

const $slots = useSlots();

defineProps({
    data: Array
});

const columns = computed(() => {
    const header = [], cells = [];
    let idx = 0;
    $slots.default().map(vnode => {
        if(! ('isColumn' in (vnode.type.props ?? {}))) return; // detect the Column component in production
        header[idx] = vnode.props?.label ? 
            () => createTextVNode(vnode.props.label) : () => vnode.children.header?.();
        cells[idx] = vnode.props?.prop ? 
            ({item}) => createTextVNode(item[vnode.props.prop]) : props => [h(vnode.children.default, props)];
        idx++;
    });
    return {header, cells};
});

</script>

<template>
 <div>
     <table>
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th v-for="(child, column) in columns.header" :key="column">
                     <component :is="child"/>
                 </th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr v-for="(row, index) in data" :key="index">
                 <td v-for="(cell, column) in columns.cells" :key="column"> 
                     <component :is="cell" :item="row"></component>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
 </template>

TheColumn.vue:
<script setup>
defineProps({
  isColumn: Boolean
})
</script>
<template></template>


I would suggest to change the template structure like this:
The Column component is designed to accept scoped slots for the header and cell.
The TheTable component passes these slots down to the Column component, using the slotProps to bind the necessary data.
The App.vue component provides the actual content for the slots, determining how the header and cell should be rendered based on the data and translation logic.
App.vue
<template>
  <TheTable :data="data" :columns="columns">
    <template v-slot:header="{ label }">
      {{ translate ? translatedLabels[label] : label }}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:cell="{ item, column }">
      <span v-if="column.prop === 'city'">
        {{ translate ? cities[item.city] || item.city : item.city }}
      </span>
      <span v-else>
        {{ item[column.prop] }}
      </span>
    </template>
  </TheTable>
</template>

TheTable.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <Column v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index" :label="column.label" :item="item">
      <template v-slot:header="slotProps">
        <slot name="header" v-bind="slotProps"></slot>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:cell="slotProps">
        <slot name="cell" v-bind="slotProps"></slot>
      </template>
    </Column>
  </div>
</template>

Column.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="header">
      <slot name="header" :label="label">{{ label }}</slot>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <slot name="cell" :item="item"></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

